# How can I pass Data type(like int,char,.....) Dynamically?

Tags: java, class, collections, dictionary

I am trying to create Dynamic class. Now I want to read Field Data types from console how can I do.Here I am passing one as a Data type of a field and another one is Field name.

Below is my code:

```
1. Map <Class <?>, String> fields = new HashMap <Class<?>, String> ();

2. Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
3. System.out.println("enter field Name");
4. String a=s.nextLine();  //Ex: id (I passed "id" as field name)

5. fields.put(int.class,a);  //here how can I pass int.class from console
```

O/p:

```
int id;
```

In Line Number 4 I read the String from console and put in map(Line number 5).

Now I want to read "int.class" type from console to put into my Map.

If I passed like above in Line Number 6 it's creating field(int id).But how can I pass that one Dynamically   How can I read the .class type from console

Comment: You can't do that with primitives (int, float).

Comment: I got o/p like above but now I want to pass Data type to my field name from console instead of hard code . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName(String className)` but that won't work for primitives. Use `java.lang.Integer` instead.

Comment: What input I will give. Integer.class, If I given like this it will throwing ClassNotFound Exception

Comment: As i said: `Class.forName("Java.lang.Integer")`

Comment: Same exception occurred again

Comment: I can't really tell what you are trying to do here... Creating a Map that contains the name of a Class provided by the console as a key and the Class itself as value?

Well, a is the name of the Class right? So: 5. `fields.put(Class.forName(a), a)` should work.

Comment: In that way also I passed but exception occurred

Comment: Sorry, it has to be "java.lang.Integer"